# Please tell me how to split a numerical columns or node in Decision Tree

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree, supervised-learning

Please tell me how to split a node that has a numerical value, like suppose my parent node is temperature and it has numerical values 45.20, 33.10, 11.00, etc. How should I split such kind of numerical values? If I have a categorical column like temperature having a low and high value, I will split it low on the left side and high on the right side. But how should I split the column if it is numeric?

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/24339/40260

Comment: Read this, all the details of decision tree are explained within: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/04/complete-tutorial-tree-based-modeling-scratch-in-python/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decision tree using continuous variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889344/decision-tree-using-continuous-variable)

Answer (score 1):

There are discretization methods for converting numerical features into categories e.g. for using in Decision Trees. There are many supervised and unsupervised algorithms, from a simple [Binning](https://www.saedsayad.com/binning.htm) to Information Theoretic approaches like [what Fayyad & Irani proposed](https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/93-2/Papers/022.pdf). Follow [this tutorial](https://www.saedsayad.com/binning.htm) to learn how to discretize your features. The algorithm by Fayyad and Irani is explained in [this course](https://www.experfy.com/training/courses/feature-engineering-for-machine-learning).

Disclaimer: I am the instructor of that course.